# COnvert £'s to $'s

Tags: java, currency

Hi may seem a bit of a dumb question but does anybodyknow some simple Java code to convert uk £'s to us $'s? Thanks!

Comment: I think this varies based on the daily exchange rate.  You'll probably need some online source that can supply you with this conversion rate.

Comment: why cannt you go for javascript, have a javascript method to change based on locale change

Comment: There are webservices offering this service, see this similar question for a few of them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632472/currency-conversion

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to consume a web-service which can Provide real-time currency foreign exchange information and calculations.

example
http://www.xignite.com/xCurrencies.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 5):

```
String currency = "£100";

currency = currency.replace( '£', '$' );
```

:)

Comment: I worked at a place where they used this kind of thinking :D I only lasted 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the £/$ rate, just do 100$ * £/$ rate = x £. Note that for financial calculations it is generally advisable to use BigDecimal, although in that simple case the precision errors should not be that big a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple calculation will do:

1 U.S. dollar = 0.6201935 British pounds (Taken from Google)

```
var exchangerate = 0.6201935;
var dollars = 10;
var pounds = dollars * exchangerate ;
```

or

```
var exchangerate = 0.6201935;
var pounds = 10;
var dollars = pounds / exchangerate ;
```

Comment: Don't forget to round the answer. I can assure you the exchange rate doesn't have more than 5 digits of accuracy. ;)

Comment: `var`? That's not Java. (Note, JavaScript is not Java).

Comment: This is javascript and not Java. the declarations are incorrect.

Comment: Its not meant to be either, its just showing the process so the op can uses it in what ever language they want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that rate of exchange may vary day to day so there are some websrvcies which will provide you day to day change of exchange rate. Please adopt those.

Answer (score 0):

The change rate for GBPUSD is usually quoted as how many dollars you get for one sterling. This could be 1.61162.

```
double rate = 1.61162;
double dollars = 10;
double pounds = round(dollars / rate, 2); // round to two decimal places
```

or

```
double pounds = 10;
double dollars = round(pounds * rate, 2);
```

You can use BigDecimal, but the process is the same.

Exchange rates can change many times per second. Its also worth noting that you get a different rate depending on whether you are buying or selling dollars. i.e. if you buy dollars and then sell them you usually won't get as much money back.

Comment: Argh! Never use `double` for storing amounts of money.

Comment: @Jesper, Most of the investments banks I have worked in *only* use `double` for money. Tradionally trading systems were written in C/C++, do you think they used BigDecimal? no.

Comment: Ok, but still I think this is bad practice. Better is to use an `int` or `long` and store amounts in cents instead of dollars, euros or whatever.

Comment: @Jesper, I agree int/long is better, even short is appropriate in some cases.  Working with fixed precision has it own quirks and if you have prices which can be "not present", having NaN is handy.  In my case I use Integer.MIN_VALUE with extra checks which I won't have to do with double.